# Changing a Windows CE machines IP address programatically?

Tags: compact-framework, ip-address, windows-ce

How do I change the IP address of a Windows CE machine?

I want to do it from .NET Compact Framework!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter the current IP address by writing a new value out to the registry at HKLM\comm[adaptername]\Parms\Tcpip.  Keep in mind that this is a *multi-sz* value and that for the change to take affect, you *must* call the NDIS driver with the [IOCTL_NDIS_REBIND_ADAPTER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901403.aspx) IOCTL.

As Shaihi points out, the [Smart Device Framework](http://smartdeviceframework.com) already ahs all of this wrapped up in the NetworkInterface.CurrentIpAddress property.